# get value after onsubmit dropdown

Tags: php

I have a little bug I do not find the solution, I am close but he miss me something.

When I arrive on my product catalog page, I have this url

http://localhost/admin/index.php?A&Catalog\Products&Products

I click on my categories dropdown, My url become :

http://localhost/admin/index.php?A&Catalog\Products&Products&cPath=

As you see the value of `cPath` do not exist but if I display the value of echo $_POST['cPath']
I have my number

The problem, my link inside the form do not want to take the value, I need to click twice on my dropdown to have the `$_POST['cPath']` value.

```
     $post_cPath = '';
    
      if(isset($_POST['cPath'])) {
        if(!empty($_POST['cPath'])) {
          $post_cPath = $_POST['cPath'];
        }
      }
    
      echo $post_cPath; // I see this value after the first click but below it do not want to take the value, just after the second click.

      echo HTML::form('goto', $products->link('Products&cPath=' . $post_cPath), 'post');
```

Thank you.

HTML code

arrive in the page

```
<form name="goto" action="http://localhost/Admin/index.php?A&Catalog\Products&Products&cPath=" method="post">
<select name="cPath" onchange="this.form.submit();" class="form-control form-select"><option value="" selected="selected">--- Haut ---</option><option value="14">Camera</option><option value="8">Components</option><option value="9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mice and Trackballs</option><option value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Monitors</option><option value="2">Desktops</option><option value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MacBook</option><option value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PC</option><option value="3">Laptops & Notebooks</option><option value="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mac</option><option value="6">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Windows</option><option value="13">Phones & PDAs</option><option value="12">Tablets</option></select>               </form>
```

after the categories selection
The `cPath` has a value

```
<form name="goto" action="http://localhost/Admin/index.php?A&Catalog\Products&Products&cPath=13" method="post">
<select name="cPath" onchange="this.form.submit();" class="form-control form-select"><option value="" selected="selected">--- Haut ---</option><option value="14">Camera</option><option value="8">Components</option><option value="9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mice and Trackballs</option><option value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Monitors</option><option value="2">Desktops</option><option value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MacBook</option><option value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PC</option><option value="3">Laptops & Notebooks</option><option value="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mac</option><option value="6">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Windows</option><option value="13">Phones & PDAs</option><option value="12">Tablets</option></select>               </form>
```

but my urk is always like that

http://localhost/admin/index.php?A&Catalog\Products&Products&cPath=

my cPath value is empty. I need a value after the first click and no after the second click

Comment: If you need to click twice, then there is likely an issue with Javascript. Can you show the code that triggers this action?

Comment: see above I hope it helps you